# What are these .dll's that I see embedded or referenced in web pages?

Tags: dll

I'm researching how to build some tools in my website and as I'm looking around examples of similar tools in other websites, I've noticed the source code referring to .dll files.  I'm relatively new to web development, so I'm only accustomed to seeing references to script files.  What are these .dll's that I see referenced in web pages?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a perfectly reasonable question for someone who's new to web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just server side code that will generate HTML (or JS/CSS/Images), similar to .php files or Java Servlets.